# Sentinel-2 Query scihub apihub wget missing results

Tags: query, sentinel-2, copernicus

When I perform a search in Firefox using

```
https://[username]:[password]@scihub.copernicus.eu:443/dhus/search?q=footprint:"intersects(41.9000, 12.5000)" AND ((platformname:Sentinel-2))
```

I only get to see 10 of the 443 results with no option to see the others, same in IE.

When I use wget to get results as XML it's the same, I get an XML output with 10 results using:

```
wget  --continue --config wgetrc "https://[username]:password]@scihub.copernicus.eu:443/dhus/search?q=footprint:\"intersects(41.9000, 12.5000)\" AND ((platformname:Sentinel-2))" -O c:/downloads/test6.xml
```

How do I get it to produce an XML output with all 443 results?

A manual search in the hub does allow me to see all foubd images

Answer (score -1):

just needed &rows=100 in query